# use mysql as persistence motor in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to change sqlite to mysql for work with ruby on rails, but as I am a newbie in this, I have a problem

The first that I did was to go a GemFile and include the mysql gem. I am working in local

localhost:3306 using LAMP

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.19'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2'
gem 'hirb'
```

After I configurate the file database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: blog_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: strlen12
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock


  test:
    adapter: mysql2
    encoding: utf8
    database: blog_development
    pool: 5
    username: root
    password: strlen12
    socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

  production:
    adapter: mysql2
    encoding: utf8
    database: blog_development
    pool: 5
    username: root
    password: strlen12
    socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

but when I try to run rake db:migrate this error is triggered

```
fernando@fernando:~/ProyectoTicketMaster/TicketMaster$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
/home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ticket_master/gems/mysql2-0.3.17/lib/mysql2/client.rb:70:in `connect'
/home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ticket_master/gems/mysql2-0.3.17/lib/mysql2/client.rb:70:in `initialize'
/home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ticket_master/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `new'
/home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ticket_master/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `mysql2_connection'
/home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ticket_master/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
/home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ticket_master/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
/home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ticket_master/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
/home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ticket_master/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
/home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ticket_master/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
/home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ticket_master/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
/home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ticket_master/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
/home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ticket_master/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
/home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ticket_master/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ticket_master/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ticket_master/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
/home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ticket_master/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:310:in `clear_cache!'
/home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ticket_master/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:103:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ticket_master/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__875551666__prepare__678451887__callbacks'
/home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ticket_master/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
/home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ticket_master/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
/home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ticket_master/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ticket_master/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
/home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ticket_master/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
/home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ticket_master/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ticket_master/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ticket_master/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ticket_master/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ticket_master/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ticket_master/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ticket_master/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ticket_master/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/home/fernando/ProyectoTicketMaster/TicketMaster/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ticket_master/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ticket_master/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ticket_master/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ticket_master/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ticket_master/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/home/fernando/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@ticket_master/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/application.rb:305:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Version of Mysql installed in my pc

```
fernando@fernando:~/ProyectoTicketMaster/TicketMaster$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.38, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.2
```

Comment: remove this "socket: /tmp/mysql.sock" then have a try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the socket path for MySQL in your file my.cnf (usually in the */etc/mysql/* folder) :

```
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

you can check if mysql is running with the following command:

```
mysqladmin -u root -p status
```

If you make any changes make sure you restart your server. Also you could use the localhost connection:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: my_db_name
  username: root
  password: my_password
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306
```